# How to access static files in a collection?

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

How do I access static files in a collection?

I have (I think) followed the instructions at

https://jekyllrb.com/docs/collections/

I created a dir `./_test` and static files `./_test/a` and `./_test/b` and added a corresponding collection entry in `_config.yml`:

```
collections:
  - test
```

After this I cannot use `site.test.files` to get an array containing the files `./_test/a` and `./_test/b` (as should be possible, per my interpretation of the above Jekyll documentation).

(I use the Jekyll version provided by GitHub-Pages.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say you have both, some files with yaml front matter and static files witch are not processed by jekyll. These files can be accessed as follows:

- files with front matter:

  ```
  {% assign test_docs = site.test %}
  {{ test_docs }}
  ```
- static files:

  ```
  {% assign test_coll = site.collections | where: "label", "test" | first %}
  {{ test_coll.files }}
  ```

As you asked explicitly for static files, in the code above `{{ test_coll.files }}` contains the array with both files `/_test/a` and `/_test/b`. **But**, only if these files do not have a yaml front matter.